gnu make -n behaves oddly for &: targets
I have a makefile where I'm trying to build multiple targets in a single rule. I'm using the new grouped targets feature in GNU Make 4.3.
Here's my sample makefile:
obj1 &: source
        touch $@

obj2: obj1
        touch $@

If I create source and then try to build obj2, it behaves as expected, touching first obj1 and then obj2. Fine.
But then I do this:
$ touch source
$ make -n obj2
touch obj1

It rebuilt obj1, but it didn't rebuild obj2 for some reason. However, if I change the &: to a : --- only possible because in my test case I only have a single target --- it works fine:
$ cat test.mk
obj1 : source
        touch $@

obj2: obj1
        touch $@
$ touch source
$ make -f test.mk obj2 -n
touch obj1
touch obj2

If I try this with -d, I get the following from the first, failed example:
...
touch obj1
  Successfully remade target file 'obj1'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'obj2'.
 Prerequisite 'obj1' is older than target 'obj2'.
No need to remake target 'obj2'.

...but this from the second, working one:
...
touch obj1
  Successfully remade target file 'obj1'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'obj2'.
 Prerequisite 'obj1' is newer than target 'obj2'.
Must remake target 'obj2'.
touch obj2
Successfully remade target file 'obj2'.

What gives? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? It feels to me that in the &: case, it's failing to remember that it's fake-built obj1 when looking at the dependencies for obj2, meaning that it then stats the real file and gets the wrong timestamp.
Any ideas?

This looks like a bug to me.

Yeah, looking at this the next day I agree. I've reported it; I'll update this if they answer.
